# one to many models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm laying out a simple app using movies and reviews.
I've got the index, new and create action defined but my edit and delete actions are whack.
My delete action is deleting the movie rather than the review, and i have no idea how to pick up the review in the edit action. Thanks.

reviews controller.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        @reviews = @movie.reviews
    end

    def new
        @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        @review = @movie.reviews.new
    end

    def create
        @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        @review = @movie.reviews.new(review_params)
        if @review.save
            redirect_to movie_reviews_path(@movie), notice: "Thanks for your review!"
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        @review = @movie.reviews
    end

    def destroy
        @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        @review = @movie.review
        @review.destroy
        redirect_to movie_reviews_path(@movie), notice: "Review successfully deleted."
    end


private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:name, :stars, :comment)
    end

end
```

review model.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :movie

  validates :name, presence: true

  STARS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  validates :stars, inclusion: { in: STARS, message: "must be between 1 and 5" }

  validates :comment, length: { minimum: 10 }

end
```

movies controller.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @movies = Movie.all
end

def show
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end


def edit
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    if @movie.update(movie_params)
        redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie successfully updated."
    else
        render :edit
    end
end

def new
    @movie = Movie.new
end

def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
        redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie successfully created."
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
        @movie.destroy
        redirect_to movies_url, notice: "Movie successfully deleted."
end







private

def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :rating, :total_gross, :description, :released_on)
end

end
```

movie model.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :reviews

validates :title, presence: true

RATINGS = %w(PG PG-13 R NC-17)

validates :rating, inclusion: { in: RATINGS }

validates :total_gross, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

validates :description, length: { minimum:10 }

validates :released_on, presence: true

end
```

routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "movies#index"

  resources :movies do 
    resources :reviews
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `edit` action on `ReviewsController` first finds movie based on `:movie_id` param and then assigns all reviews related to found movie to variable `@review` which is bad.
You should find just one review:

```
def edit
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

Regarding `destroy` action of `ReviewsController` it doesn't delete movie. It finds movie based on `:movie_id` param, and tries to find review which will give error since this method doesn't exist on `@movie` instance. In your `Movie` model class you have `has_many :reviews`. This gives you `reviews` method which gives you all reviews related to that movie.

Anyway to delete certain review you don't need movie:

```
def destroy
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.destroy
    redirect_to movie_reviews_path(@movie), notice: "Review successfully deleted."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the movie and review id based on your nested resource. In the reviews controller:

```
def edit
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def delete
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then do your subsequent actions. The ID is unique, hence you don't need to bother about the movie_id in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the controller methods you're looking for:

movie.rb

```
class Movie

def edit
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end

def delete
  movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  movie.destroy

  redirect_to movies_url, notice: "Movie successfully deleted."
end
```

review.rb

```
class Review

def edit
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def delete
  review = Review.find(params[:id])
  review.destroy

  redirect_to movie_reviews_path(review.movie), notice: "Review successfully deleted."
end
```

(You don't need the object in the delete method to be an instance variable, since you're not persisting it outside the method.)

Also, a tip to avoid hardcoding the STARS variable in your Review class.

```
validates :stars, inclusion: { in: 1..5, message: "must be between 1 and 5 }
```